# get params is undefined in while handling drawer navigators

Tags: react-native

```
const paymentstacknavigator=createStackNavigator({payment:{screen:Paymenti}},{ navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    initialRouteName: 'payment',
    headerMode: 'screen',
    headerTitle: 'Payments',
    drawerLabel: 'Payments',
    drawerLabel: 'Payments',  drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Image
        source={require('./img/Paypng.png')}
        style={{width:20,height:20}}
        />
    ),
})})

const trackstacknavigator=createStackNavigator({track:{screen:Tracki}},{ navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    initialRouteName: 'track',
        headerMode: 'screen',
        headerTitle: 'track',
        drawerLabel: () => null
})})


const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({   
    payments: {
        screen:paymentstacknavigator
    }
    track:{
      screen:trackstacknavigator
    },
          },{initialRouteName:'signup',drawerType:'slide'},
    );

const App = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);
export default App;
```

**In track.js**

```
componentDidMount(){
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    var s=navigation.getParam('objectid', 'NO-ID');
    console.log('mone',s)
    console.log('one',this.props.navigation.state.params)
}
```

**Labs.js**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('home', { customernumber: value });
```

**What I expected**

The variable `s` in `track.js` has a value from `labs.js`

**what happened**

The variable `s` in `track.js` is `undefined`

When I run the above code, and when I try to do the navigation from lab to track and also carrying data from that to this, it doesn't do the work it gives me null , I suspect that there is misunderstanding with drawer navigation to me, because this is the first time that I am passing the data to a component in drawer navigator